# Access Flask Request Object In Eve check_auth method

Tags: flask, eve

I can't figure out how to access the request object when the `check_auth()` method gets called. It provides the resource and the method  (GET, POST) etc, but not the actual request data itself. How do I add a hook for that? I can't use Eve's event hooks because they get called after the `check_auth()` event. But I want to do some validation of the data in the check_auth().

I found `from flask import current_app` as a way to get at flask `current_app`, but I want the current request, not the whole app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this

```
from flask import request
```

And you will have access to the global `request` object. 
See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.request for more.